# One to many navigation property is null in code first EF5

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

What is the proper way of defining related collections in code first Entity Framework 5?
I was following this [summary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx?Redirected=true) but something is not working.

I have the following model:

```
class Order
{
  public Guid Id {get; set; }
  public DateTime Created {get; set;}
  public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines {get; set;}
}

class OrderLine
{
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  public Guid OrderId {get; set;}
  public Order Order {get; set;}
  public string Product {get;set;}
}

class OrderContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

There is an `Order` with some lines in the database. When it is loaded it's `OrderLines` property is null.

I have tried making `OrderLines` virtual, it did not help.
Otherwise, everything is set to default. Lazy load is true, CreateProxy is true...

When I try to `Include("OrderLines")` it works and fetches the lines from DB.

Comment: You need to configure the relationship between them, using Fluent APi would be the best

Comment: Have you enabled lazy loading? Or try using Include

Answer (score 2):

In `OrderLine` try placing a FK annotation over the navigation property:

```
class OrderLine
{
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  public string Product {get;set;}

  // 1:many with Order
  public virtual Guid OrderId {get; set;}
  [ForeignKey("Id")]
  public virtual Order Order {get; set;}      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the data annotations to annotate the foreign key attribute.  You don't need to do it with Fluent API anymore.

```
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines {get; set;}
```

I would have thought it would create that by default.